# How to change the font of percent signs?

Tags: fonts

In my document below, I would like to change the font of all percent signs to the font of the attached image. How can I do it?
BTW, I'm using XeLaTeX on TL2012.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\%}
\[
\%
\]
\begin{tabular}{c}
$\%$ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``\renewcommand{\%}{\texttt{\char`\%}}``

Comment: @egreg This isn't what I was looking for. The font differ from what I want.

Comment: Find the font of the attached image. How can I know it? *You* wrote `\texttt`; just use in its place a font command choosing that font, in the form ``\renewcommand{\%}{{\thatfont\char`\%}}``

Comment: It's hard enough to recognise a font from a text sample at the best of times but doing it from a single character is virtually impossible. Where did that image come from? have you not got it in a form that you can exactly determine the font, eg as a pdf file or word file or tex file or anything else where you have the internal structure rather than just a bitmap image?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know the font. It's `pcrr8a`. To be clear, I'm using `XePesian` which is a package for writing Persian in XeLaTeX.  I can easily obtain the desired font in the normal text, but I can't get it in math mode or tabular environment. Any advice would be helpful to me.

Comment: why didn't you say that in the question? or make a MWE that at least loaded the font or in any other way gave people the slightest clue?

Comment: pcrr8a is just an 8 letter name of an 8bit encoding for old systems, you just want courier which you can load as a system font in xetex and use in maths just by using \text{\texttt{\char`\%}}  after having set up texttt to use courrier rather than computer modern

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought this problem is solved by some commands or macros. Sorry for that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks so much for your great hint. Please change your comment so that I can accept it as my answer. Of course it would be great to provide some more info about pcrr8a.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pcrr8a` is just an 8 letter name of an 8bit encoding for old systems, you just want Courier which you can load as a system font in xetex and use in maths just by using

```
\texttt{\char`\%}
```

after having set up `\texttt` to use Courier rather than computer modern

Comment: yes I did a double  edit, will simplify